# Unknown IceCast fails

Tags: linux, centos, node.js, sockets, icecast

I have a node.js script, which works in daemon mode. The script reads IceCast ogg stream itself (on the fly) and sends audio tags to website. But sometimes (exactly once per 2 days) the script fails end exits. The error log of the script says:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND stream_url stream_url:8000
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error’ event
```

Where “stream_url” is the real ogg stream URL.

Also I have noticed that if change *stream_url* on some another working ogg stream (not mine, just found via Google), no error occurs anymore. IceCast error log says nothing about it, just INFO and few WARN about web (favicon).

It seems IceCast crashes or disables domain or port/socket somehow, or maybe not itself, but causes that effect.

What might the problem be?

P.S. OS is CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the NodeJS documentation for [dns.lookup()](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback) to get an idea what's going wrong.

This has *nothing* to do with Icecast. NodeJS fails to resolve the FQDN/hostname (in that sense `stream_url` is a misnomer) to an IP address. This can potentially have many reasons like:

- NodeJS ran out of resources or stalled
- The system ran out of resources
- The resolver DNS that was queried didn't answer (properly)
- The Internet connection to the resolver was down
- The authoritative DNS server for that FQDN didn't answer
- …

Your actual use case is best addressed in other ways like querying the Icecast JSON API endpoint, parsing its playlist.log or getting the data from the source client.

Comment: Icecast JSON API is very poor, there are no cover, year, album tags and more others. So what is the exact reason not to use node.js in this case? Both the node.js script and Icecast are running at the same VPS machine.

Comment: I take 'very poor' as an insult! It provides access to all public state that the server extracts. If you are streaming Ogg encapsulated audio, then it can have many (non-standard, even) fields. We will provide more access in Icecast release 2.5. If you need more metadata than we provide, then accessing the stream directly or having the source client dump out the data is the only way. -- For me this question is settled and I do _not_ appreciate your tone and thus will not reply further.

Comment: my apologies, didn't want to insult you, I think you misunderstood my tone or I really wrote my opinion with wrong words. Anyway, if Icecast really provides cover tag, then this is my fault as newbie (I'm not pro in audio topics). Thank you for your answers!